# How to sum across columns after pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the `groupby()` operation on a pandas dataframe. I am then trying to sum the columns together for each row. However I keep getting an error when calling `sum()`.

I have attached my code below:

```py
bike_use = bike_use.groupby(['road_name', 'count_point_id'])['pedal_cycles', 'two_wheeled_motor_vehicles'].sum(axis = 1)
```

And the error that I get is:

```
TypeError: sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Even though the documentation for summing and pandas dataframe and a pandas series, [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) both allow the keyword `axis`.

I don't know why it throws this error even though the functions allow it to take this as a keyword?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want double `sum` - first aggregate by `sum` by [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and then sum both columns with `sum(axis=1)` by [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
bike_use = bike_use.groupby(['road_name', 'count_point_id'])['pedal_cycles', 'two_wheeled_motor_vehicles'].sum().sum(axis = 1)
```

But if need sum 2 columns without groupby:

```
bike_use['both'] = bike_use[['pedal_cycles', 'two_wheeled_motor_vehicles']].sum(axis = 1)
```